# What would be best method to append bootrap css to non bootstrap themes but not affect layout?

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

I want to use Adaptive themes, I like the layout options, however, I like the Bootstrap look and feel.

So I want Adaptive theme layout css with boostrap visual css basically.

What would be the best way to achieve this short of getting into the HTML of Adatptive them and changing all the classes on elements?

Comment: I came to know that, I am not only that came across this dilemma..:) I too started with Adaptive theme, which has very good UI for setting up media-queries and separate CSS file for screen size, but do not have look and feel like bootstrap. Will keep this question under radar as I also want to know.

Comment: @clive - I don't think this should be marked as off topic. The OP is asking how to come up with a solution to a problem he has. Namely, he has installed one theme which he is happy to use for the layout.css but would now like help integrating some styling from another stylesheet (theme.css from bootstrap). He is not asking anyone to recommend a book, tool, module, theme, etc - just how to add another css sheet to an existing theme.

Comment: @Mark he is literally, both in the title and in bold face, asking for a tool recommendation

Comment: @Bruno as always, "best" is subjective. If your question is what Mark surmised, "how do I add a CSS file to a theme?", that's been answered already, here and in countless other places. If it's "how do I mix arbitrary CSS from 2 different themes?" or "how do I get all of the options from one theme into another", then the question is obviously much too broad for Q+A. If you're building this new theme yourself, feel free to ask **specific** questions as they come up

Comment: Ok, sounds good, will do

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your bootstrap package for download here:

> Customize Bootstrap's components, Less variables, and jQuery plugins to get your very own version.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

After that, you can add just the required CSS/JS to your theme as per the usual methods